# Sqlbox change spaces to plus sign

Tags: sms, kannel

I have installed and setup kannel and Sqlbox. I can do insert on the send_sms table and the message is sent throught the gateway.

The only thing i'm facing is that kannel or Sqlbox is converting the spaces in SMS into + , flor example

Hello world => Hello+world

Can somebody tell me why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: This is a new one ??? What version are you using ???

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of text message in Kannel is stored as URL-encoded string and space is represented as plus sign.